# Made a website with GitHub, font doesn't show on all browsers, operating systems, and devices?

Tags: html, css, github, fonts, responsive-design

I made a website with GitHub and the font I used (Lato) only seems to be showing on Google Chrome, but just on macOS and Android phones. Safari, iPhones, and Windows laptops display Times New Roman instead. I'm not sure what the issue is, since I picked Lato for being a Google font? Shouldn't it work across all browsers/operating systems/devices? Am I supposed to upload the font folder in my GitHub repository? Also don't know if it matters, but my code used "font-family" to call in Lato. Should I not be using that?

EDIT: adding my code for reference

HTML

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3fdadcecb8.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
```

CSS

```
.title {
    font-family: "Lato";
    text-align: left;
}
.text {
    font-family: “Lato”;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: left;
}
.bold {
    font-family: "Lato";
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Comment: No code that shows off your actual ([mcve]) HTML and CSS means no one can answers this question except you.

Comment: Do you have the following in your <head>:  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans sorry about that, thought I didn't need to do that because I literally just have "font-family: Lato" in my CSS

Comment: @fraggley I do not! I will give that a try

Comment: @fraggley Added that to the head of my html files, it didn't seem to change anything :/

Comment: If that's all you have, then only systems with that font install can load it, which you can't rely on. If you want a _specific_ font, make sure to load that font using a webfont (e.g. the abovementioned google webfont css)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following into your `<head>` tag:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Then your CSS should be as follows:

```
.body {
    font-family: "Lato";
}

.title {
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 3em;
}

.text {
    color: black;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.bold {
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Here is a working example: https://codepen.io/fraggley/pen/YzyaNJa

Comment: Sooo I did this and it worked perfectly, but now it's not working again? Only change I've made since was adding a favicon, not sure how that could've affected it?

Comment: Can you update your question including the full header (and the favicon code)

Comment: Just updated. Initially, my favicon code was below fonts. I tried moving it above just now but nothing changed

Comment: I just tested it and it works fine on mine (except for displaying the favicons as i don't have those). Make sure you are doing a hard refresh (ctrl + shift+r) in your browser. Let me know what browser / device it's not working on.

Comment: Also check your console in the browser to see if you are getting any errors

Comment: What browser/device are you viewing on?? I just checked my iPhone on safari and it still doesn’t work. My friend also checked her Dell laptop and it’s showing Times New Roman too

Answer (score 0):

I FIXED IT.

Basically, what caused the issue was enforcing https on my website. The font was linking to an http, so I just changed it to https and now it works :D